# Install Developer Edition ASE in Vagrant/Virtual Box

Tags: sybase, virtualisation, sybase-ase

It is possible to deploy a development version of Sybase in a Vagrant/Virtualbox instance?  I was planning on using a CentOS vagrant box to create a development environment but am not sure if it's even feasible to run ASE in a virtual environment.

If possible, are there any caveats to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Sybase within a virtual environment purely for development purposes is possible and I have used it that way for years with Windows, Linux and Solaris x86. I'm not sure about Vagrant, but with Virtual Box it works.

You must ensure your virtualised host has sufficient memory to run the database and have made the relevant additional settings.

You'll need to set the maximum amount of shared memory to a suitable value and there is probably a dependency on libaio1.

For example, add the following to /etc/sysctl.conf. If 1GB is too large you can use a smaller value. You'll need to consult the Sybase documentation for the version you're installing for a minimum value.

```
# Set the kernel shared memory to 1GB
kernel.shmmax=1073741824
```